# Unable to click Element Using Selenium Webdriver(Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a button that is present on the right side of the graph(Three lines above the graph) and finally want to click on "Download as CSV". My code is as below.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= ChromeDriver_Path, options = options)
driver.get('https://www.kansascityfed.org/data-and-trends/labor-market-conditions-indicators/')
time.sleep(5)

element =  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="highcharts-zn6tkt8-0"]/div[1]/div[2]/button'))).click() ##Error here
```

File = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="highcharts-3slsa4f-0"]/div[2]/ul/li[6]'))).click() #Download as csv

Error:
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException

My XPath looks correct but still, the element is not getting clicked.

Answer (score 1):

so i dont know if Iam doing something wrong but I did try to search your element by the XPATH youre searching for and Iam not able to find it

Comment: The exception youre getting also kinda tells thats its not finding anything, but 20 seconds should be more than enough to load the side